# replacing words using array without using IF conditional, etc

Tags: c#

I got this condition

My array:

[image]

What i want is to replace all the words in array1 into array2 or array2 to into array1 without IF condition, anyone can help?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to replace "A" with "Q" and "R" with "B"?

Comment: Please paste actual code rather than a picture of the code. If we need to copy or edit it, especially with all that punctuation, you're making our job a lot more challenging. Also, please read [ask] since you're new here.

Comment: @JRLambert I'm wondering the same thing. A little less ambiguity here and it should be a simple solution.

Comment: As stated please explain in a detailed form, we're here to help. But if you expect people to help and not provide a way to do so then I've got a bad news for you.

Comment: TBH guys, I thought the question was fairly obvious and straight forward.
replace entries in string 1 with an equivalent replacement from a second string without using an if statement.
like a replacement cypher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the string functions for replace and a dictionary for the assignments.

here is a simple example:

```
string array1 = "@ABC";

Dictionary<char, char> dict = new Dictionary<char, char>() { { '@', 'P' }, { 'A', 'Q' }, { 'B', 'R' }, { 'C', 'S' }};

foreach(var item in dict){
    array1 = array1.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);}
```